# How to change the loading photo and favicon of the Flet project on deploying?

Tags: python, flutter, user-interface, frontend, flet

I created a project with flet and I intend to customize the logo during loading and its favicon.
I went according to the instructions and created a folder called assets and then put the icons and png folder of the two files and then changed their names according to the instructions.
Although the favicon had the minimum pixel size, it was not applied.
What's worse is when I uploaded these to github and created the folders and put the images in there, but when I deployed with cloudflare, none of them applied.